# Email not case sensitive in django allauth

Tags: django, django-allauth

How can i set an email as no case sensitive with Django Allauth?
I want to save it in lowercase in database but not exist a parameter like ACCOUNT_PRESERVE_USERNAME_CASING.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can achieve this

1. Use Django-Allauth configurations setting

```
ACCOUNT_PRESERVE_USERNAME_CASING = False
```

So that every email/username gets stored as lower case and queries are being run using `__iexact` on it.

2. Or overwrite Django save method

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.email:
             self.email = self.email.lowercase()

        super(User, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: With the first method, using ACCOUNT_PRESERVE_USERNAME_CASING, only the username is saved in lowercase. The email remains indifferent.

Comment: is your username and email field the same or they have different entries at DB level
? If yes we can set email as user name at model level.

Comment: Oh no, they have different entries in DB